# Fundamentals of Rendezvous and Proximity Operations

Tags: orbital-mechanics, astrodynamics, rendezvous

I am trying to work out how to calculate / model a rendezvous and proximity operation between two spacecraft. I have read several research papers, but none of them walk me through step by step how to do the calculations. I would ultimately like to be able to model things in NASA GMAT or write MATLAB code to do things.

1. Where can I find the necessary algorithms for calculating RPO?
2. Is there a tool available, such as NASA's GMAT, to help me model RPO?

Comment: Please revise your post to *ask a question* that can have *a definite answer*.  Please review the help center https://space.stackexchange.com/tour